# Display a value other than the one in the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this text box defintion in my view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MaxNumberOfExtensions == "0" ? "Unlimited" : model.MaxNumberOfExtensions, new { required = "required", id = "maxNumberOfExtensions" })
```

What I am trying to do is say,

> If the value MaxNumberOfExtensions is 0 then display 'Unlimited' in
>   the text box, otherwise display, the value in the field
>   MaxNumberOfExtensions

This does not work at runtime.  It gives the error

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such complex lambda expressions are not supported by the HTML helpers. They only support property access and indexer access expressions.

The correct way is to use a view model of course. So you would have a property which will already contain the required text based on the value of your domain model.

For example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string MaxNumberOfExtensions { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your controller action rendering this view:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    SomeDomainModel model = ...
    MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel();
    viewModel.MaxNumberOfExtensions = model.MaxNumberOfExtensions == "0" ? "Unlimited" : model.MaxNumberOfExtensions;
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

and then in the view:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MaxNumberOfExtensions, new { required = "required", id = "maxNumberOfExtensions" })
```

Alternatively if your application is currently not following best practices (not using view models) you could write a custom template where you could perform this task.

For example, add the following template in `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/FormattedNumberOfExtensions.cshtml`:

```
@model string
@{
    var value = Model == "0" ? "Unlimited" : Model;
}

@Html.TextBox("", value, new { required = "required", id = "maxNumberOfExtensions" })
```

and then in your view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.MaxNumberOfExtensions, "FormattedNumberOfExtensions")
```